# microsoft VBA - ‘object doesn’t support this property or method’

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create a macro that will follow few steps:

1. Open reference document sent to me on email (this changes Everytime) as well as exported document saved.
2. In exported document I add a column and call it XLOOKUP column. I do the XLOOKUP from the document number in this file to the WCC ORDER NO in other file and looking up the INV NETT.
3. i also need to make sure the new column made is set as ‘General’ instead of ‘Text’ format
   4.Then filter on this new XLOOKUP column for 0’s and delete any rows with 0 value
4. On the ‘No.’ column filter for any blanks and delete these rows
5. Now copy and pasta the XLOOKUP column under the column in the original exported document which is called ‘Direct Unit Cost’
   7.You then delete the XLOOKUP column because the original document needs to be in same format it was exported in.

This is the code:

```
Sub AutomateDataImport()
Dim exportedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim referenceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim xLookupRange As Range
Dim xLookupColName As String
Dim xLookupColNumber As Long
Dim directUnitCostCol As Variant
 
'Prompt for the reference workbook
Dim referenceFilePath As String
referenceFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If referenceFilePath = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Reference Document not selected. Exiting."
    Exit Sub
End If
 
Set referenceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(referenceFilePath)
 
 
'Prompt for the exported workbook
Dim exportedFilePath As String
exportedFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If exportedFilePath = "False" Then
    MsgBox "Exported Document not selected. Exiting."
    Exit Sub
End If
 
Set exportedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(exportedFilePath)
 
'Determine XLOOKUP column name and number
xLookupColName = "WCC ORDER NO"
xLookupColNumber = 3
On Error Resume Next
xLookupColNumber = referenceWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(xLookupColName).Column
On Error GoTo 0
 
If xLookupColNumber = 0 Then
    MsgBox "XLOOKUP column not found in the reference document."
    Exit Sub
End If
 
 
 
'Add a new column for XLOOKUP and set it as 'General' format
Set exportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Add
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Value = "XLOOKUP Column"
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "General"
 
'Filter and delete rows with 0 in the xlookup column
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count, Criteria1:=0
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False
 
'Filter and delete all rows with blanks in the 'No.' column
directUnitCostCol = exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find("Direct Unit Cost").Column
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=directUnitCostCol, Criteria1:="="
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=directUnitCostCol, Crtieria1:="<>"
On Error Resume Next
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False
 
'Copy and paste the XLOOKUP Column under 'Direct Unit Cost'
referenceWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(xLookupColNumber).Copy
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(directUnitCostCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False
 
'delete XLOOKUP Column
exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Delete
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `exportedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Add` ... what are you trying to do with this line? Did you mean to use `.Insert`?

Comment: I needed to add a column in the exported document named xlookup column where i can perform the xlookup from the reference file.

The code is not working from after it prompts me to select both the files i want to use, after it opens them both it brings the error 'object doesnt support this property or method'.

Comment: `.Columns` doesn't have an `.Add` method.